# How to use IIS app_offline.htm file with Azure

Tags: azure, filesystems, app-offline.htm

I have a brilliantly designed **app_offline.htm** file that I'd like to display on my site periodically when I'm doing things like backing up the DB. On a server with a real file system, this wouldn't be a problem: I'd just copy app_offline.htm to the my app's root, and IIS will work its magic and redirect all requests to this file.

However, I'm using **Azure**, so there's no *real* file system and there's no easy way move files around from one location to another.

How I can I make app_offline.htm play nicely with Azure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there *is* a real file system, as each VM instance runs on Windows 2008 Server (SP2 or R2 SP1). To see this for yourself, enable Remote Desktop for your deployment and connect to a running instance.

Knowing this, you should be able to set up a mechanism to perform a file-copy of your app_offline.htm to your app root based on some type of administrative command. You'll just need to make sure each of your web role instances perform this action.

Comment: Let's assume that I keep the app_offline.htm in my "/images" directory located just off the root.  So you're saying that after deploying the package to Azure, I should be able to execute an admin command or batch file to copy app_offline.htm from "/images" to "/" and that I can do this all from a Remote Desktop connection? As I noted below, my co-found is the Azure expert on the team, so please excuse my ignorance in this area. I was under the impression that File I/O type actions were pretty hard to do on Azure once the new bits had been pushed to the cloud.

Comment: Persistent changes to the file system are more challenging when they are not part of the package.  However, if you have a mechanism to copy the file over (say a simple process that watches a table or queue), this is trivial to implement.  David is correct.

Answer (score 6):

I figured I'd add this, I haven't seen it mentioned yet. You can actually do this via web publish from Visual Studio (or WebMatrix) as well, just put **app_offline.htm** in the **root of your project** - the same level as your main web.config. When done, just rename it and redeploy to go back online. 2 clicks - easy.

The manual option is to drop it into your **/site/wwwroot** via FTP.

A little personal secret, none of your site files will be accessible, style sheets etc. So put your includes into an azure blob container, and viola.

Answer (score 2):

David has provided you with a good answer.  However, you might be missing out on what Azure can do for you.  You should be able to virtually eliminate down time with Azure by running multiple instances and using SQL Azure which is triple backed up for you.  You can also backup SQL Azure using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff951624.aspx

Comment: My co-founder is actually the Azure expert on our team, and we are already running multiple instances with SQL Azure. However, earlier today, he needed to update the DB schema which meant that part of the site was down for several minutes. When I hit the site, I was redirected to my main ErrorPage. But I would have preferred to have had the app_offline.htm file in the root during those few minutes. I was just under the impression that it's non trivial to be doing file I/O related things on an Azure deployment.